# Expected number of lightbulb failures

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A company has a lightbulb replacement policy that says to replace a lightbulb either when it stops working or at regularly scheduled times, $T, 2T, \ldots$, regardless of how old the lightbulb is.

If the lifetime of the new lightbulbs are i.i.d random variables, each exponentially distributed with mean $1/\lambda$, what's the expected number of lightbulbs replaced in a single scheduling interval (make sure to include the one lightbulb scheduled during the interval, say, at the beginning)?

---

I guess if we let the lifetime of each bulb be the sequence $X_1, X_2, \ldots$, then the time that the $i$th lightbulb stays in service is $\min(X_i, T)$. Also I have the p.d.f of each $X_i$ since they're exponential. But I am not so sure how to compute the expected number of bulbs changed.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: No.  The *times between bulb failures* are independently exponentially distributed with mean $1/\lambda$.  What is the distribution of the *count of bulb failures* in an interval $(0..T)$ ?

Comment: What is the expected value for that Poisson Distributed random variable ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.  Put it as an answer and accept it.